Как лучше организовать API на Node.js
Я пишу API на Node.js. Для обработки запросов использую встроенный модуль http, которым создаю сервер на определённом порту и перебираю запросы через switch, case. Количество конечных точек растёт, и у меня начинают возникать вопросы связанные с быстродействием:

Сколько одновременных запросов может обработать один такой сервер?
Имеет ли смысл создавать дополнительные на других портах в том же, или отдельном файле?
Резервирует ли каждый отдельный сервер объявленный в одном файле, какой-то определённый фиксированный размер памяти? То, что отдельный файл представляет из себя отдельный процесс и забирает на себя часть памяти я уже понял наблюдая за ним в pm2.

P.S. стараюсь не использовать сторонних модулей, чтобы глубже понять как работает чистый Node.js

1 - все зависит от действий на сервере. 2 - лучше использовать кластеризацию. Немного тут описывал. 3 - нет, будет есть столько, сколько нужно
